# OpenGL Similar to multiply effect for lighting

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

So I'm working on a game and I'm wondering how I would achieve a similar effect to multiply in photoshop but in OpenGL. Too explain it better I have attached some images showing the steps that it would go through.

So to start with I have my image, which I render normally.

[image]

I then draw a black screen over it all.

Then I have my lights image, these are just white gradients.

[image]

After that I apply my multiply effect in photoshop:

[image]

How would I go about achieving the same effect but in opengl?

The lights would also have to blend together.

It doesn't matter how the effect was created in photoshop however, as long as I can create the same ending result.

I'm using LWJGL.

Comment: I think it would be better to do it in a shader, what shader language do you know?

Answer (score 1):

1. Draw the light image to the screen.
2. Enable blending with function `glBlendFunc(GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO)`
3. Draw your other objects to the screen.

The resulting fragments drawn will be the multiplied value of the background (light) and incoming objects (quads).

Comment: It really nearly works. But all the images are slightly transparent?